# PostgreSQL count(boolean expression)

Tags: postgresql, count, logical-operators

What is the best way in Postgresql, I want to count how many count with `value = 1` in field A and how many count  with `value = 0` in same field A.

something like this:

```
select 
    count (field1 = value1) as filed1_ok, 
    count (field1 = value2) as filed1_bad,
    extract(MONTH from rpt_date) AS mth
where rpt_date between frdate and todate
group by mth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `count(condition or null)`

```
select
    count(field1 = 1 or null) as filed1_ok,
    count(field1 = 0 or null) as filed1_bad,
    extract(MONTH from rpt_date) AS mth
where rpt_date between frdate and todate
group by mth
```

`true or null` evaluates to `true`. `false or null` evaluates to `null`. Since `count` does not count nulls that is exactly what you want.

In other SQL dialects and also in Postgresql it can be done using `case`

```
select
    coalesce(sum(case field1 when 1 then 1 end), 0) as filed1_ok,
    coalesce(sum(case field1 when 0 then 1 end), 0) as filed1_bad,
    extract(MONTH from rpt_date) AS mth
where rpt_date between frdate and todate
group by mth
```

I consider it verbose and opaque compared to the `count(condition or null)` Postgresql option.